# Lists in python - return value once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to make a function that takes a empty list and returns the values only once (even if the same value is entered several times).
Example
input from user:

```
list=[a,b,b,c,d,d,d,e,f]
```

The function returns then:

```
list=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

(does not have to be in chronological order, does not matter)

What I have done so far is:

```
def func1():
    list=[]
```

Comment: `return list(set(your_list))`

Comment: Also, does the user enter that as text verbatim? Or do they just enter the letters and then those letters are added to a list

Comment: Don't assign to `list` name. Then you `list()` something and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

```
def func1():

    list1=[]
    while(1):
        val = input("Enter the value\n")
        if val == 'exit':
            return list(set(list1))
        list1.append(int(val))
print(func1())
```

Comment: @peterovic: Is this what you are expecting ? If yes, please confirm this as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use set that  returns unique value

```
In [44]: def func1(l):
    ...:     return [x for x in set(l)]
    ...: 

In [45]:  l=['a','b','b','c','d','d','d','e','f']
    ...: 

In [46]: func1(l)
Out[46]: ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f']

In [47]:
```

Answer (score -1):

You just simply make it below

```
def func1(mylist):
    return list(set(mylist))
```

and call your method as :

```
newList = func1([1,1,2,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: What is the reason of downvote? I really curious about it. If you explain what you want to do so may be the answers could be more helpful.